# using variables in csdef file for VirtualDirectory

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-web-roles

we are hosting 3 different web applications in azure machine and we are using CI to push this changes from build server TFS in the azure to our machines.

the trouble is in physicalDirectory porperty as we could not find any possibily to use any of build-variables there, so we have to use relative path like this

```
physicalDirectory="..\..\..\..\..\..\bin\_PublishedWebsites\xxxxxx"
```

we have two issues with this, one is that the loca build and hosted build needs different  relative paths, and second is that one our two branhces are not on same level.

I tried

```
physicalDirectory="$(OutpuPath)\_PublishedWebsites\xxxxxx"
```

as well as

```
physicalDirectory="%OutpuPath%\_PublishedWebsites\xxxxxx"
```

had no success with any of those.

is this possible at all, if not is there any other way to replace this values?

thanks
almir

Answer (score -1):

You can define your own environment variables in azure, this approach may work for you
"http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432991.aspx"

Comment: but my question was, how I can use those in my csdef file, and replace the existing value there. I could not find any samples for that